# Many youtube videos don't load but show a "loading" icon instead

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, youtube, html5

I installed Windows 8.1 2 days ago and I'm pretty sure that's when this issue started. About half of the youtube videos I try to watch are infinitely stuck at this screen:

[image]

It seems that rightclicking the videos that have this show it's the HTML5 player whereas those that work use the Flash player (at least: that's what the context menu indicates).

I have tried both working and not working videos in Internet Explorer and they both work there.

I'm using Google Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m. I used to use the Youtube Center plugin as well but enabling/disabling this makes no difference.

According to https://www.youtube.com/html5 everything HTML5 should be supported:

[image]

Right now it is set to use the standard player instead of the HTML5 one; changing it either way doesn't solve anything.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Edit:

A friend verified that he has the same problem on his Windows 8.1 installation. I just tried it on my laptop as well (Windows 8) and the issue occurs there as well.

You can try it yourself with [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3i2op_vwX8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly every video works again even though I haven't changed anything. When my friend wakes up I'll ask him to confirm his troubles are gone as well, but for now I think it's safe to assume that Google fixed something on their end.

Should the problem arise again in the event it is on my side after all, I will put a bounty to attract attention.